# Filter out data of table if table-row consist a zero

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering how I can I delete a row if that row contains a 0?

This is how my table looks like without the filtering method:
[image]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

is that possible somehow with JQuery? I just use a simple HTML table: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4q9euj29/)

```
<table>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <th class="resultModule">
                 Module
             </th>
             <th class="resultCredits">
                 Credits
             </th>
         </tr>        
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test A
             </td>
             <td>
                 0
             </td>

         </tr>                    
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test B
             </td>
             <td>
                 8
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test C
             </td>
             <td>
                 0
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test D
             </td>
             <td>
                 6.5
             </td>
         </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*P.S. I do not want to use any Database related answers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to find rows where the second `td` element contains a `0`, and then `remove()` them. Try this:

```
$('table tr').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() == '0';
}).remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4q9euj29/3/)

Comment: Please mark it as answer to avoid confusion to others if you think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, but I got a timelimit where I must wait for 10 minutes to actually accept the answer @SherinMathew

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) like

```
$('tr:has(td:contains(0))').remove();
```

```js
$('tr:has(td:contains(^0$'))').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <th class="resultModule">
                 Module
             </th>
             <th class="resultCredits">
                 Credits
             </th>
         </tr>        
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test A
             </td>
             <td>
                 80
             </td>

         </tr>                    
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test B
             </td>
             <td>
                 8
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test C
             </td>
             <td>
                 0
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Test D
             </td>
             <td>
                 6.5
             </td>
         </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update**

Note, above **will break** if there happens to be text which contains 0 like 80. In that case you can do

```
$('tr:has(td:contains(0))').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:contains(0)').text() == '0';
}).remove();
```

Comment: this will also delete the elements if it contains zero. lets say 80.., like that

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, is that better?

Comment: Looks good now. (I think 'td:contains(0)' selector is only needed once. ). Didnt downvote you though :)